How to use try-catch in trigger
I want to prevent inserting data into a table and return 'Error' if 'OrderDate' column is greater than '2021-01-01'. How can I do this by the use of TRIGGER and TRY...CATCH in sql-server v.2019



OrderID
OrderDate




10015
2019-05-06


10016
2020-06-01


10017
2020-06-02



CREATE TRIGGER date_check ON Sales.Orders AFTER INSERT  
AS
    BEGIN TRY
    INSERTED.orderdate<'2021-01-01' 
    PRINT 'NO ERROE'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR'
    END CATCH
GO


Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884334/tsql-try-catch-transaction-in-trigger

This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140138/trigger-with-a-raiserror-and-else-case-issue

I don't think you need try catch in this scenario

The attempt you've done won't prevent anything anyway, it'll just change what is returned in the messages. If you want to prevent a value, why not use a CHECK CONSTRAINT?

i would go with the CONSTRAINT, or INSTEAD OF INSERT.  then IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE testDate < '2024-07-01')) BEGIN...END.  so if it matches you do the insert otherwise you dont.

There is literally no need for a TRIGGER here, just use a CONSTRAINT:
ALTER TABLE Sales.Orders ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Orders_orderdate CHECK (orderdate < '20210101');

Then any DML statements that attempt to store a value on or after 01 January 2021 will cause a constraint error, and the DML statement would fail.
If you "had" to do it in a TRIGGER, which you really don't, then you have a couple of problems:

The column inserted.orderdate has no context; you can't just arbitrarily reference a column from a table without a FROM.
Your attempt wouldn't even stop an INSERT, it would just result in a different message appearing in your client. The DML statement would still complete.

Instead use an EXISTS to check if the value exists in the INSERTed data, and then THROW an error. Borrowing syntax I use in a post I wrote which also grabs the name of the table and trigger causing the error generically, we could do something like this:
CREATE TRIGGER Sales.trg_Orders_orderdate ON Sales.Orders
AFTER INSERT/*, UPDATE*/ AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted i
               WHERE i.orderdate >= '20210101') BEGIN
        DECLARE @TriggerName sysname,
                @TableName sysname;
        SELECT @TriggerName = tr.name,
               @TableName = t.name
        FROM sys.tables t
             JOIN sys.triggers tr ON t.object_id = tr.parent_id
        WHERE tr.object_id = @@PROCID;
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2000) = FORMATMESSAGE(N'An error occurred in the trigger ''%s'' on the object ''%s''. The column ''orderdate'' cannot have a value on or after 2021-01-01.', @TriggerName, @TableName);

        THROW 98765, @ErrorMessage, 16;
    END;
END;

Of course, you could just hard code the error. I just like my TRIGGERs to be informative to the users when they cause an error, as then when they come "complaining" to me, I know what the root of the problem is and thus wrote something I can copy pasta.

Thanks for your help Thom. I learned new things in your answer but it is a homework and I am asked to solve it by the use of TRIGGER and TRY...CATCH. Thanks anyway

Thank you guys for the help.I solved it by the following code:
 CREATE TRIGGER date_check ON Sales.Orders AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN TRY
IF (SELECT max(orderdate) FROM INSERTED )<'2021-01-01' 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
ELSE 
PRINT 10/0 --Explanation:This step is to creat a wrong condition which leads to CATCH step otherwise "IF" condition wont create error and CATCH was never reached
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'ERORR: An inserted order is registered after 2021';
END CATCH

